Развертывание Django проекта на сервере Linux
Я занимаюсь разработкой backend части web приложения.
Мы используем язык Python, фреймворк Django и СУБД Postgresql. Скоро мы должны "сдружить" наш  frontend и backend и для этого я должен буду развернуть back на вм, вм на Linux(ubuntu). Я искал много инфы для этого и пока не нашел что-то годное. Для теста попробовал развернуть на вм cloud.ru но безуспешно. То что я попровал это было временное, но мне надо продакшн-окружение. Если вы скинете хороший гайд или вы сами пропишите все был бы очень благодарен

https://habr.com/ru/articles/790886/

и да, лексикон как-то подбирайте ...
